# Get href within a DIV and place it in window.location.href

Tags: jquery

Say I have

```
<div id= "page">
<div class = "container">
<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to get that url within "container" and only inside "page" and place it in window.location.href with jquery?  I know there are probably better ways of getting to that URL but I just want to know if this is possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want the link *within "container" and only inside "page"* the selector has to be

```
window.location = $('#page .container a').attr('href');
```

Comment: the **container** is class your code works with the **container** as **id**

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = $('#page .container a').attr('href');
window.location = url;
```